# Connecting images with lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I tried to make match two pairs with lines quiz. I have couple of images on left, and couple of images on right, and I need to connect it with lines when you click on pair of images. It should work for any combinantion, so if I click for example on image 1 on left and image 3 on right, they should be connected with line. Then if I click again on image 1 on right, and image 2 on left, previous line should be deleted, and the new one between those two images need to be made.
Html snippet:

```js
function lineDistance(x, y, x0, y0){
    return Math.sqrt((x -= x0) * x + (y -= y0) * y);
};

function drawLine(a, b, line) {
  var pointA = $(a ).offset();
  var pointB = $(b).offset();
  var pointAcenterX = $(a).width() / 2;
  var pointAcenterY = $(a).height() / 2;
  var pointBcenterX = $(b).width() / 2;
  var pointBcenterY = $(b).height() / 2;
  var angle = Math.atan2(pointB.top - pointA.top, pointB.left - pointA.left) * 180 / Math.PI;
  var distance = lineDistance(pointA.left, pointA.top, pointB.left, pointB.top);

 // Set Angle
  $(line).css('transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)');


  // Set Width
  $(line).css('width', distance + 'px');
                  
  // Set Position
  $(line).css('position', 'absolute');
  if(pointB.left < pointA.left) {
    $(line).offset({top: pointA.top + pointAcenterY, left: pointB.left + pointBcenterX});
  } else {
    $(line).offset({top: pointA.top + pointAcenterY, left: pointA.left + pointAcenterX});
  }
}
new drawLine('.a', '.b', '.line');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
  <div id="old" class="left_side one_half svg left">
    <a href="#" data-number="1"><img class="a" src="assets/svg/Kerze.svg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-number="2"><img src="assets/svg/Telefon.svg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-number="3"><img src="assets/svg/Schreibmaschine.svg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-number="4"><img src="assets/svg/TV_old.svg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-number="5"><img src="assets/svg/Zeitstopper.svg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-number="6"><img src="assets/svg/Besen.svg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-number="7"><img src="assets/svg/Waschen.svg"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="left_side one_half svg right">
    <a href="#" data-letter="NS"><img src="assets/svg/Iwatch.svg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-letter="RT"><img src="assets/svg/Laptop.svg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-letter="TE"><img src="assets/svg/Staubsauger.svg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-letter="IN"><img src="assets/svg/Waschmaschine.svg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-letter="EI"><img src="assets/svg/TV_new.svg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-letter="AL"><img src="assets/svg/Gluehbirne.svg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-letter="BE"><img class="b" src="assets/svg/Iphone.svg"></a>
    <div class="line"></div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

I manage to make a line between two images (from class a to class b), and it is always calculated to be exactly on right angle, but I can not make it appear to work as I described above. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var setLeft = false, setRight = false;
$('.leftSide img').click(function(){
    $('.leftSide img').removeClass('a');
    $(this).addClass('a');
  setLeft = true;
  new drawLine('.a', '.b', '.line');
});
$('.rightSide img').click(function(){
    $('.rightSide img').removeClass('b');
    $(this).addClass('b');
  setRight = true;
  new drawLine('.a', '.b', '.line');
});
```

You can use a flag variables and when click on an image from the right, set the right flag variable to be true and do the same with the other.

Then inside your function `drawLine` just check if the two flags are true then draw the line between `a` and `b` and set the two flag variables to `false`.

```js
function lineDistance(x, y, x0, y0){
    return Math.sqrt((x -= x0) * x + (y -= y0) * y);
};

function drawLine(a, b, line) {

 if(setLeft && setRight){
   setLeft = false;
    setRight = false;
    var pointA = $(a).offset();
    var pointB = $(b).offset();
    console.log(pointA);
    console.log(pointB);
    var pointAcenterX = $(a).width() / 2;
    var pointAcenterY = $(a).height() / 2;
    var pointBcenterX = $(b).width() / 2;
    var pointBcenterY = $(b).height() / 2;
    var angle = Math.atan2(pointB.top - pointA.top, pointB.left - pointA.left) * 180 / Math.PI;
    var distance = lineDistance(pointA.left, pointA.top, pointB.left, pointB.top);

   // Set Angle
    $(line).css('transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)');


    // Set Width
    $(line).css('width', distance + 'px');

    // Set Position
    $(line).css('position', 'absolute');
    if(pointB.left < pointA.left) {
      $(line).offset({top: pointA.top + pointAcenterY, left: pointB.left + pointBcenterX});
    } else {
      $(line).offset({top: pointA.top + pointAcenterY, left: pointA.left + pointAcenterX});
    }
  }
}
//new drawLine('.a', '.b', '.line');
var setLeft = false, setRight = false;
$('.leftSide img').click(function(){
 $('.leftSide img').removeClass('a');
 $(this).addClass('a');
  setLeft = true;
  new drawLine('.a', '.b', '.line');
});
$('.rightSide img').click(function(){
 $('.rightSide img').removeClass('b');
 $(this).addClass('b');
  setRight = true;
  new drawLine('.a', '.b', '.line');
});
```

```css
.left{
  float:left;
}
.right{
  float:right;
}
.one_half{
  width:40%;
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
}
.line{
  background: red;
  height:1px;
}
.question{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
  <div id="old" class="left_side one_half svg left leftSide">
    <a href="#" data-number="1"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-number="2"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-number="3"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-number="4"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-number="5"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-number="6"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-number="7"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="left_side one_half svg right rightSide">
    <a href="#" data-letter="NS"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-letter="RT"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-letter="TE"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-letter="IN"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-letter="EI"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-letter="AL"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#" data-letter="BE"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"></a>
    <div class="line"></div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.That is a good start, just there is a problem that line is only show for one pair, when I click on another pair og images, previous line is gone, and also, it works great when you click image on right that is below image on left, when I tried to pair image on right that is above image on left, the line does not connect good.